# How to view files of directory in UI

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a directory and I read all the files inside it.
But I need a way to view file content.
Ex: show image if the file is image or show text in case the file is text or pdf and so on.
This is my code to read files from folder:

```
$main_dir = "directories/{$user->email}";
                chdir($main_dir);
                $dh = opendir('.');
                while ($file = readdir($dh)) {
                    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { ?>
                        <tr id="soso">
                            <td class="file-name">
                                <?php
                                if (filetype($file) === 'dir') { ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $main_dir . "/" . $file ?>" target="_blank"><i class="far fa-folder"></i><?php echo $file ?></a>
                                <?php
                                } else {
                                ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $main_dir . "/" . $file ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $file ?></a>
                                    <em><?php echo $file ?></em>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="extension">
                                <?php
                                $path = pathinfo($file);
                                if (filetype($file) === 'dir') {
                                    echo 'folder';
                                } else {
                                    echo $path['extension'];
                                }
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="date">
                                <?php echo date("F d Y H:i:s.", filectime($file)) ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="manage">
                                <span class="view" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-file-modal" data-file="<?php echo $file ?>"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></span>
                                <form action="classes/deleteFile.php" method="POST">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="fileName" value="<?php echo $file ?>">
                                    <button type="submit" name="deleteFile" class="delete"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                }
                closedir($dh);
                ?>
```

finally, this is a image of my code and there is an aye icon, I want to show file in modal for example when click the file eye icon.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using bootstrap modals. Replace the source of the image in the modal when it's shown.

```
$('#view-file-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var $invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);
  // Use $invoker to retrieve the image url from correct element
  $('#view-image').attr("src", "someimage.jpg");
});
```

If the modal can be triggered for other data types as well and not just images, I'd probably add a listener to the view buttons themselves and programmatically show the modal from there while setting the modal's content.